# Is it possible to get display name from inside concat in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

So let's say I have this Model:

```
class Cable(models.Model):
    id = models.OneToOneField(Item, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=choices.cableTypes, default=1)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    length = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    objects = CableQuerySet().as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.get_type_display()) + " Cable, " + str(self.length) + "m"
```

I need to be able to pull results from the database using the `__str__`, and that has proven to not be possible. So instead, I was advised to use `.annotate()` with `Concat()` to achieve the same result.

My problem is that I need the display name of `Cable.type` and not the value, or I need to be able to use the value of `type` as the key, and search the choices with that to then return the proper value.

Is it possible to get display name from inside concat, or is there something that I can do that provides a similair outcome?

**EDIT:** Here are the cableTypes:

```
cableTypes = (
    (1, "Not Specified"),
    (2, "XLR"),
    (3, "DMX")
)
```

Comment: The display name is *not* stored in the database, so no, unless you inject that mapping in the expression, but that should result in quite "ugly" code I think.

Comment: I'm willing to create functional code at the cost of beauty, this is just functionality that I really need. It makes sense that I would need to inject, but would that also include more database hits?

Comment: can you share the `cableTypes`? (or at least the "shape")? Is it a tuple of 2-tuples? list of 2-tuples? etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've added the `cableTypes` to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You strictly speaking *can* do that, but usually it is better *not* to do that, since it results in a query that does not *look* very nice.

We can use an annotation here to replace the `type` to its display equivalent, like:

```
from django.db.models import Case, CharField, Concat, Value, When
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

Cable.objects.annotate(
    text = Concat(
        Case(
            *[When(type=t, then=Value(d, output_field=CharField()))
              for t, d in choices.cableTypes],
            output_field=CharField()
        ),
        Value(' Cable, ', output_field=CharField()),
        'length',
        Value('m', output_field=CharField()),
        output_field=CharField()
    )
)
```

The `Cable`s that arise from this queryset, will have an extra value named `text` that contains a string that has, I hope, the same value a `__str__` would yield.

For example:

```
>>> Cable.objects.create(type=2, length=1.2)
<Cable: XLR Cable, 1.2m>
>>> qs.all()[0].text
'XLR Cable, 1.20m'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I totally get what you mean by not an attractive solution now, but it works flawlessly!